# IE 10 won't load with Protected Mode enabled

Tags: windows-7, security, internet-explorer

I discovered recently that I could not open IE.  The window would open, appear for a few seconds, then disappear.

I run Webroot security, but installed Ad-aware and ran a scan.  I also ran HiJackThis and removed some old gunk.

I disabled all toolbars, Add-ons, uninstalled all Adobe products, and disabled most all non-essentiall services from MSConfig.

Still, IE would not open.  Finally, I disabled Protected Mode under the Security Tab of IE Options.  Everything worked!  If I re-enabled Protected Mode, the problem returns.  If I run in IE (No Add-ons) mode, the browser will load, but I cannot navigate anywhere.  This started under IE and followed through the upgrade to IE10.

Has anyone seen this or have ideas?  Yes, I run Firefox.  Still, I want this resolved.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling IE10 and reinstalling?

Comment: I uninstalled IE10, which took me back to 9 (where the problem originated).  Lo and behold, that resolved the issue.  I could enabled protected mode and IE would start.  I then re-downloaded IE10 and reinstalled.  The exact same problem returned.  In IE10 with Protected Mode enabled under the Security Settings, the browser will not start.

Comment: I guess I will wait and try the 11 beta.  Thanks Moses.